# Setting up a MySQL database, avoiding multiple database table accesses

Tags: php, mysql

I do have a single database and nearly about 11 tables. While my web page is opening, information from these 11 tables will be accessed at the same time. According to my current settings what I did now is for each table database is opening and closing. Say I had given a username and password to open a database for each table and close after retrieving information from that table.

Is this the right way to do it?? I feel because of this, the database is opening and closing 11 times!!!! Am I right?? Is this the right way to do that?

Oh well, I do have some tables whose update date is different from others...

Comment: do you use all 11 tables on the same page? what is stored in these tables?

Comment: yes I do use all tables on the same page..informations from various resources.

Answer (score 1):

Since the tables are in the same database, it's not necessary to keep closing and re-opening the database. Use [mysql_connect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) the first time, and then subsequent calls to e.g. [mysql_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) will reutilize that same connection, if you don't provide a new one.